# Possibility of multiple projects with Code First Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to know if it's possible to create multiple projects with the same Entity framework 5(here Code First) and if you have a complete example?

I also want to use MVP pattern in my solution.

I've saw one problem: the database is created with the first run but just for one projects not all.

I know that's not really accurate... but I just want to know if it's possible..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my last project we developed a database which captures the business domain and we also stored security-related tables in the same database but in a different schema. The domain model in visual studio included all the tables, but data access was separated into two projects. The first one was a data access layer that deals with essential business tables, and another one was a custom security authentication which had mappings related to security tables.

In addition to this, to add to complexity :-), we also added a number of DbContext-inherited classes (in our DAL) that capture the essence of the domain with which a user is working. For example, Human Resources context deals with HR-related tables, Logistics context deals with logistical tables, etc.

Comment: I have over 16 years of software development and architecture experience. That's about it that I can give your for now. However, I would suggest your read Microsoft Application Architecture Guide, 2nd edition. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673617.aspx

Comment: Ok Thank you. But i can change anything in the architecture guide except (maybe) this entity framework ;).